# how to dismiss a subview after checking whether it is already added, with the same button action?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I use the following code to add a date picker view to my app main view, on clicking a button.

```
- (IBAction)CalenderButton_Click:(id)sender
{
// code to add date picker -mydatepicker

//animating


    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];


    CGRect onScreenFrame=myPicker.frame;
     CGRect offScreenFrame=onScreenFrame;
     offScreenFrame.origin.y=self.view.bounds.size.height;
     myPicker.frame=offScreenFrame;
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
     myPicker.frame=onScreenFrame;
     [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

two things i need to implement is,

1.this code animates the view from bottom, how can i animate it from top??

2.if i click the button to add date picker again, i should check whether the view is already added, if yes, remove the sub view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question number 2: Use a boolean value to check whether the date picker is already in the view.
`isSubView` is a `BOOL` to check ,your `myPicker` is in the subview.

**UPDATED:**

```
- (IBAction)CalenderButton_Click:(id)sender
{

//animating

   if(!isSubview){
      isSubview = YES;
      [self.view addSubview:myPicker];
 /*    
      CGRect onScreenFrame=myPicker.frame;
      CGRect offScreenFrame=onScreenFrame;
      offScreenFrame.origin.y=self.view.bounds.size.height;
      myPicker.frame=offScreenFrame;
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
      myPicker.frame=onScreenFrame;
      [UIView commitAnimations];
 */    

// to slide your view from the top
     [myPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -200, 320, 200)];
     [myPicker setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
     [myPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
     [UIView commitAnimations];

    }else{
      isSubview = NO;
      [myPicker removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Comment: if(![self.view.subviews containsObject:myPicker])

Comment: we can check existence of subview by this method too.....can anyone help me to add this view from the top?

Comment: An easier way to see if `myPicker` is in place is to check `if (myPicker.superview)`